# Imported object distorts on scale

Tags: objects, scale

I have a distortion problem when I scale an object. I have applied all transformations, ie rotations are all 0, scales are all 1. Whether I use XYZ Euler or Quarternian rotation, I cannot scale to either local or global axes without distortion occurring. The object was pasted from another drawing (ie using 2 copies of Blender, & copy & paste.) There are no constraints. It seems like all the vertices have incorrect axis data, a diagonal offset or something . . .
Anybody know how to fix? 
Link to file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/2i35cj8fvyr81o8/Distorted.blend?dl=0

> > Thanks for your answer - I zeroed the deltas also, what I really needed to do was align the object's longest dimension with the global y axis, ie pointy end looking straight forward. It seems that only a custom orientation to view will do this. Seems like there might be a hotkey or something specifically for this.

Comment: Please, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share .blend files here (paste the provided link in the question text), as it's free, integrated, and permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Your object is behaving that way because it has some custom "delta transforms":

[image]

and scaling along an axis in object mode behaves like this:

[image]

If you scale it in edit mode it seems correct, though.

After resetting delta location/rotation to zero, and resetting location (<kbd>ALT</kbd>kbd>G):

[image]

it scales as expected:

[image]